# Jetpack Compose Map throwing this when TalkBack is turned on. -> java.lang.IllegalStateException: LayoutNode should be attached to an owner

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-map

I'm using Jetpack Compose to display a Google Map with text at the bottom. The app works as expected when TalkBack is turned off, but crashes when TalkBack is turned on.

I'm not sure which component is causing the issue, but I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LayoutNode should be attached to an owner
```

Can anyone help me identify and fix the issue?

```
@Composable
fun LocationPickerScreen(
    uiState: LocationPickerScreenContract.UiState,
) {

    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

    val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp


    val currentLoc = uiState.locationInfo.addressLatLng

    val cameraState = rememberCameraPositionState()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = currentLoc) {
        cameraState.centerOnLocation(currentLoc)
    }

    val marker = LatLng(currentLoc.latitude, currentLoc.longitude)

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            GoogleMap(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(screenHeight - 300.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                cameraPositionState = cameraState,
                properties = MapProperties(
                    isMyLocationEnabled = true,
                    mapType = MapType.HYBRID,
                    isTrafficEnabled = true
                )
            ) {
                Marker(
                    state = MarkerState(position = marker),
                    title = "MyPosition",
                    snippet = "This is a description of this Marker",
                    draggable = true
                )
            }


            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(308.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            ) {

                Text(
                    text = "Data Place Holder",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .semantics {
                            contentDescription = "data"
                        }
                        .padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(
                        fontSize = 14.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                        lineHeight = 16.sp
                    ),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
private suspend fun CameraPositionState.centerOnLocation(
    location: LatLng
) = animate(
    update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
        location,
        15f
    ),
    durationMs = 1500
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Have you tried this using the new map renderer? The marker looks like it is still from the old map renderer. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer

Comment: thanks for sharing this information, I just tried the latest Map Render, Still crashing with same error for Talk back on